# Saved entity in a Spring Kafka Listener is not rollbacked on a transactional test

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-jdbc, transactional, spring-kafka

I have a `@KafkaListener` which saves a new entity using Spring Data JDBC Repository. The saved entity is not rollbacked on a test annotated with `@Transactional`

```
@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {

    private final EntityRepository entityRepository;

    private CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

    public KafkaConsumer(EntityRepository entityRepository) {
        this.entityRepository = entityRepository;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic", groupId = "group-id")
    public void consume(String id) {
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        entity.setId(id);
        entity.setNew(true);

        entityRepository.save(entity);

        if (countDownLatch != null) countDownLatch.countDown();
    }

    public void setCountDownLatch(CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
        this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class SpringKafkaDataJdbcMysqlTransactionalTestApplicationTests {

    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embeddedKafkaRule = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, true, 1, "topic");

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer;

    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository entityRepository;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", embeddedKafkaRule.getEmbeddedKafka().getBrokersAsString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        kafkaConsumer.setCountDownLatch(countDownLatch);

        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        kafkaTemplate.send("topic", id);

        assertThat(countDownLatch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();

        assertThat(entityRepository.findById(id)).isNotEmpty();
    }

}
```

I am running this using a MySQL database and I am expecting the saved entity to be rollbacked. Looks like the transaction started by the repository is not joining the transaction started by the transaction in the test because it is a transaction in a separate thread.

How to join the transaction and rollback the entity? Also, is this a good way to test this behavior?

I replicated this here: https://github.com/yraydhitya/spring-kafka-data-jdbc-mysql-transactional-test

Comment: Are you using an INNODB table? (required for transactions),

Comment: That’s because `@KafkaListener` method is not a part of transaction around `test()` method. It is performed in a different listener container thread

Comment: Yes, I am using an InnoDB table.

Is there a way to make the transaction in the listener container thread joins the test transaction? I ended up with truncating the table and it made my other tests unstable.

Comment: No, there is no. That's because transactions are thread-bound.